# Store hash value

Tags: c#, linq, authentication, hash, salt

Is there a way to store the salt for this hash method? I dont know how to do it?

Thanks.

```
    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    { 
        student.StudentID = (++eCount).ToString();
        student.Salt = GenerateSalt();
        byte[] passwordHash = Hash(student.Password, student.Salt);
        student.Password = Convert.ToBase64String(passwordHash);
        student.TimeAdded = DateTime.Now;
        students.Add(student);
    }
```

Comment: You can store it in a `byte[]`. What is the actual question?

Comment: create a new field salt on your student object, then when you generatesalt(), put the salt in the field?

Comment: sorry im still abit lost

Comment: do I just put Salt as a datamember in Student? then say something like `byte[] passwordHash = Hash(student.Password, GenerateSalt(student.Salt));`

Comment: Yes, you can do that. The Salt does not have to be kept secret.

Comment: if I try that I get no overload for generatesalt takes one arguement?

Comment: The salt generation only needs to happen when a student is created or the password changes.

Comment: yeah I know? Im just trying to store the salt for the created password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be along the lines of what you want. Not sure where these Students are being stored, but it will likely need to be changed, too.

```
[DataMember(Name = "StudentID")]
public string StudentID { get; set; }
[DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
[DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
[DataMember(Name = "Password")]
public string Password;
[DataMember(Name = "Salt")]
public byte[] Salt;

protected RNGCryptoServiceProvider random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

public byte[] GenerateSalt()
{
    byte[] salt = new byte[10];
    random.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
    return salt;
} 

public static byte[] Hash(string value, byte[] salt)
{
    return Hash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value), salt);
}

public static byte[] Hash(byte[] value, byte[] salt)
{
    byte[] saltedValue = value.Concat(salt).ToArray();

    return new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(saltedValue);
}

public void AddStudent(Student student)
{
    byte[] salt = GenerateSalt();

    student.StudentID = (++eCount).ToString();
    byte[] passwordHash = Hash(student.Password, salt);
    student.Salt = salt;
    student.Password = Convert.ToBase64String(passwordHash);
    student.TimeAdded = DateTime.Now;
    students.Add(student);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lordcheeto (btw cheetos are amazing!) I have updated my question with a possible answer does it look correct?

Comment: I dont think you need `byte[] salt = GenerateSalt();` if the datamember is already a byte[]?

Comment: @KirstyWhite As far as I can tell, it looks right. Yeah, I just didn't put a lot of thought into that.

Comment: What took you a few seconds has taken me hours lol but hey everyone learns at there own pace I guess. Now onto trying to compare my hash to a student password.

Comment: @KirstyWhite Oh, noticed something that may be wrong: `byte[] passwordHash = Hash(student.Password, GenerateSalt());`. You'll want to be getting the password from the student or something, unless you're converting old, insecure passwords to salted hashes.

Comment: hmmm `student.Password = Convert.ToBase64String(passwordHash);` take care of creating it? I use a POST method with a rest web service to build the string

Comment: `students.Add(student);` this line aswell

Comment: The problem is just that the `Hash()` method shouldn't be taking the `student.Password` string for the password ever.

Comment: Then how is it suppose to hash and salt the password?

Comment: For the initial hashing, the password can't come from the database. It has to come from the user through a textbox or something. Make sense?